# NERDTreeのgrep結果の1件目を表示させたくない

Tags: vim

NERDTreeにgrepの機能を追加する[プラグイン](https://gist.github.com/masaakif/414375)を入れているのですが、grepした結果の1件目のファイルが勝手に開かれてしまうのが嫌で開かないようにしたいのですが、うまく出来ません。
勝手に開かないようにする方法はありませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

プラグインをいじる必要があります。
38行目、

```
exec 'silent grep -rn ' . pattern . ' .'
```

これを、

```
exec 'silent grep! -rn ' . pattern . ' .'
```

このように、`!` を付けてみてください。

Comment: 出来ました！！！
ありがとうございます:-)